# Preview in AUCTex problem

Tags: emacs, latex, preview, auctex

I'm trying to use emacs+auctex to write my internship report. But I found that the preview feature doesn't work.
In fact I have made it work when using ubuntu 10.04, but now I have a new computer with 11.04 and I have problems with preview.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Then I hit C-c C-p C-b for a buffer-wide preview, it tells me:

```
error in process sentinel: preview-reraise-error: LaTeX found no preview images
error in process sentinel: LaTeX found no preview images
```

Then in the info output file, it tells me

```
Preview: Fontsize 10pt )  !name(hello world.tex) !offset(-3)  ) No pages of output. Transcript written on _region_.log.

Preview-LaTeX finished with nothing to show at Fri Jul 22 22:45:58 LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
```

Compiling and other things work well, and I have tried some time re-installing auctex, but still like this.
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I remember, AUCTeX preview works only for pictures & formulas, etc., and you have none of them.

If you want to see compiled document, then you can use standard compilation/preview sequence, that is run with `C-c C-c`... You can find more in AUCTeX documentation

Comment: But I have tried preview in the example circ.tex. It doesn't work.

Comment: do you have everything you need to generate previews? ghostscript, etc., as described in AUCTeX installation instructions? I have nothing special for preview-latex in my config (https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-tex.el) and it works out of box